# How can I make a voice transmitter receiver?

Tags: audio, analog, transmitter, receiver

How can make a system which have two circuit. And one is place at ground floor and another is in roof. We send voice (like call) one from other by pushing a switch and vice versa. It may be wired system. I want to make this system. Can you please help me?

Comment: This is a vague question as there are multiple ways to approach this. Did you have a particular concept in mind? I could technically say [to talk into a tin can that is tied to a string and have the receiver listen to your voice through another tin can](https://nirvanaphotostudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/man-and-woman-talking-on-tin-can-telephone-.jpg) but I'm sure you want something more technical than that.

Comment: This system can be wired system. Do i need to make modulator and demodulator and then through a two wire line and received at other end. How can design a practical circuit. Which will work for this 15-20ft distance. The nodes are always output but when switch is push then it take input and send to the other node. Hope  it will be clear. I am waiting for your answer.

Comment: You should edit your question to show what intercom circuits you found in your research. Then ask for help if there is something you don't understand about the circuit.

Comment: Ok let me take some time and research more and then i will inform you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need something like this [simple intercom](https://electronicsforu.com/electronics-projects/hardware-diy/simple-intercom-circuit). There are plenty of similar circuits about if you look. If this looks too complex, then buy something off eBay!

Comment: It is nearly something what I want. Thank you. Let me study this circuit.